# Find files with certain date strings

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a number of files with dates in their names:

```
file_19990101.txt
file_19990102.txt
...
file_20031231.txt
```

I want to generate an ASCII file with all files up to the date 20010320, and then a second file with files from 20010321 to 20031231. How can this be accomplished using bash commands?

My current solution is to do a bunch of find commands:

```
find . -name "file_1999*" -print > index.txt
find . -name "file_2000*" -print >> index.txt
find . -name "file_200101*" -print >> index.txt
find . -name "file_200102*" -print >> index.txt
find . -name "file_2001030*" -print >> index.txt
find . -name "file_2001031*" -print >> index.txt
find . -name "file_20010320*" -print >> index.txt
```

etc. But there must be an easier way to accomplish this task!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
for f in file_*
do
        ymd=${f#file_}
        ymd=${ymd%.txt}

        [[ "${ymd}" < "20010321" ]] && echo "${f}" >>index1 || echo "${f}" >>index2
done
```

Loop over the glob, strip the prefix and suffix, compare with the cutoff and append to one file or the other.

Edit: I missed the second condition.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in file_*
do
        ymd=${f#file_}
        ymd=${ymd%.txt}

        if [[ "${ymd}" < "20010321" ]]
        then
                echo "${f}" >>index1
        elif [[ "${ymd}" > "20031231" ]]
        then
                :
        else
                echo "${f}" >>index2
        fi
done
```